# Template for selenium test on phpunit

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-chromedriver, php-7.1

I want to write selenium test case with PHP 7.1 and phpunit 6.1 with headless chrome driver. Looks like the documentation is pretty outdated. Can anyone provide example of how to write testcase?